# How to load image folder with JFileChoose and add next ,previous button to preview image one by one in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

[image]
I'm setting JFrame with Jlabel to view image in it and this image I upload it from a folder and I added next and previous button to get next and previous images view in that Label after choosing the folder with Jfilechooser button.
after I load folder and click in the first image to be viewed and then I pressed next button to continue loading simultaneously I didn't get any image in Jlabel it was a dark screen with no images..it only shows the first image I clicked in it and next button didn't work to get next one

the first method to get an image from JFileChooser

```
private String[] getImages() {
    imgch = new JFileChooser(".");
    // File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/").getFile());
    File file = imgch.getCurrentDirectory();
    String[] imagesList = file.list();            
    return imagesList;     
  }
```

Second: to show an image

```
private void showImage(int index) throws IOException {
    String[] imagesList = getImages();
    String imageName = imagesList[index];
    File file = imgch.getSelectedFile();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(file+imagesList);
          Image newImg = 
   icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(canvas.getWidth(), 
    canvas.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    viewer.setIcon(new ImageIcon(newImg));
}
```

Comment: You probably want to post a valid [mre] with this question, to help us get to the root of the problem, and also show the results of any debugging steps that you have done. One consideration: read **all** the images from the folder when the folder is selected, and place the images as Icons into a `List<Icon>`. Then getting next and previous is as simple as getting the next or previous Icon from the List.

Comment: i added full code with sample image

Comment: *"i added full code"* Why? @HovercraftFullOfEels advised to post an MRE. It's not the same thing.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson upper two code are samples from full codes which represent the problem which i didn't solve until now.i already can make next and previous images shows but from resource dir which i set it in code and i want to select image from chosen button not specific path and also want to navigate with image in that folder with next and button key as in picture

Comment: solved by changing  imgch.getSelectedFile() to  imgch.getCurrentDirectory()
           path = file.getAbsolutePath().concat("/"+imageName) then pass path to ImageIcon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by changing this line in showImage()
`File file = imgch.getSelectedFile();`
to
`File file = imgch.getCurrentDirectory();`
`path =  file.getAbsolutePath().concat("/"+imageName);`
and then pass "path" to ImageIcon